# In $\mathbb Z[x]$, show that the set $A$ of all polynomials with even constant term is not a principal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

I'm doing *Exercise 1* in textbook *Algebra* by Saunders MacLane and Garrett Birkhoff.

[image]

> In $\mathbb Z[x]$, show that the set $A$ of all polynomials with even constant term is not a principal ideal.

Because my solution is so short that I suspect it contains subtle mistake. Could you please verify if my attempt is fine or contains logical mistakes? Thank you so much for your help!

---

The product of an even integer with any other integer is even. The sum of even integers is again even. Then $A$ is an ideal.

We have $p := x^2+x+2 \in A$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z$. If $A$ is principal, then $A = \langle p\rangle$. However, $q=2 \in A$ is not divisible by $p$. Hence $A$ is not principle.

Comment: For the first part you need to be explicit about how this applies to the constant term of polynomials not just to integers.

Comment: Your solution looks fine to me.